# Springboot error when inserting to Oracle DB using Oracle JDBC java API with DATE

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, jpa

I got the error `Caused by: Error : 932, Position : 70, Sql = insert into T_table1 (CREATED_TIME, LOG, ID) values (:1 , :2 , :3 ), OriginalSql = insert into T_table1 (CREATED_TIME, LOG, ID) values (?, ?, ?), Error Msg = ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected TIMESTAMP got BINARY`.

None of the other posts solved my problem

Main:

```
DATE th = new DATE(); //oracle.sql.DATE
LogService.saveLoggingData(new LogEntity("test log",th));
```

LogEntity:

```
import oracle.sql.DATE;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "T_table1")
public class LogEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "LOG")
    private String log;

    @Column(name = "CREATED_TIME")
    private DATE ts;

    public LogEntity(){

    }
    public LogEntity(String logEvent, DATE createdAt){
        this.ts = createdAt;
        this.logEvent = logEvent;
    }

}
```

LogService:

```
@Service
public class LogServiceImpl implements LogService {

    @Autowired
    LogRepository LogRepository;

    @Override
    public void saveLoggingData(LogEntity log) {
        LogRepository.save(log);
    }
}
```

LogRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface LogRepository extends JpaRepository<LogEntity, Long>{

}
```

Oracle Table field `CREATED_TIME` is of type `TIMESTAMP (6)`. But I am clearly inserting a nonnull `DATE` in the main, why did it become binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two problems

First, the LogEntity constructor is setting the value to the argument itself.

```
public LogEntity(String logEvent, DATE createdAt){
    this.ts = createdAt;
    this.logEvent = logEvent;
}
```

Its must be:

```
public LogEntity(String logEvent, DATE createdAt){
    this.ts = createdAt;
    this.log = logEvent;
}
```

On the other hand, I think that using the Oracle Date is not suitable for this insert. You should use the Date from the Java Util library

```
Replace oracle.sql.DATE for java.util.Date;
```

Comment: If the column in the Oracle database is of  Oracle type `DATE`, then `java.util.Date` is the wrong class in Java. (A) That class is now legacy, years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes. (B) That class represents a point on the timeline, with a date, time-of-day, and an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. A `DATE` column has only a date and time-of-day but lacks the context of an offset or time zone. So the matching type in modern Java is `java.time.LocalDateTime`.

Comment: @Basil Borque is exactly right. Use java.time.LocalDateTime for Oracle Database DATE type.